# Wordpress hook to add custom form field in term.php?taxonomy_name

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am trying to add custom form field in attribute term edit form.

This is the form where I want to add custom field:

[image]

But have not been able to find the hook. Whenever I search this hooks comes up `{$taxonomy}_add_form_fields`. But it is not for that term edit page.

Comment: If you check the source code of `term.php`, you’ll see it includes `edit-tag-form.php` at the end. So go check the code of _that_, to see which hooks are available in there in/around the place where you want to make changes.

Comment: You need to give a better problem description than just “don’t seem to work”. Please go read [ask].

Comment: Thanks alot @CBroe your solution worked. It was my mistake I was working on one installation of wordpress and testing on another. That's why couldn't see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The [`{$taxonomy}_add_form_fields`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_add_form_fields/) hook fires on the main taxonomy page to add fields in the form that appears to the left of the terms table.  The correct hook to use on this screen is [`{$taxonomy}_edit_form_fields`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_add_form_fields/).  You can find more information about the display hook [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021162/add-custom-fields-in-custom-taxonomy-meta-box-in-wordpress-3-5-2/65459566) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114266/adding-metabox-to-custom-post-type-category/46114653).

Unfortunately, you will have to generate your own HTML for display.  Additionally, you will have to save the input submitted by the user by way of the [`saved_{$taxonomy}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/saved_taxonomy/) hook (unless you have registered the meta by way of [`register_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/)).